# Divisibility of the pth Stirling number of the first kind (edit:of the second order)

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, stirling-numbers

I discovered empirically that the *p*th (*p* is prime and greater than 3) [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation) is always divisible by $p^2$. If you calculate Stirling numbers recursively than the $p$th is given by:
$$\left[(((1*2+1!)*3+2!)*4+3!)... \right]*  (p-1)+(p-2)!$$

I think we should prove it similarly to [the algebraic proof of Wilson's theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson's_Theorem#Algebraic_proof) but I don't know how exactly. Can you help me?

Example:
$((1∗2+1!)∗3+2!)∗4+3!=50=2*25$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stirling number of the first kind that you are considering here is $\left[p\atop 2\right] =(p-1)!H_{p-1}$ where $H_{p-1}=1+\frac{1}{2}+..+\frac{1}{p-1}$ is a harmonic number.

This is not an algebraic proof, but it is shown [here](http://www.math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf) that $p^2$ divides $\left[p\atop 2\right] =(p-1)!H_{p-1}$ when $p\gt 3$ is prime.

This result is also known as Wolstenholme's theorem.