# Wolstenholme-like result

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910912/divisibility-of-the-pth-stirling-number-of-the-first-kind-editof-the-second-or) earlier and found out that the answer is also known as [Wolstenholme's theorem](http://www.math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf). So the $(p-1)$-th harmonic number's numerator is divisible by $p^2$. But I also discovered that: the numerator of the $((p-1)\cdot p)$-th
 one is divisible by $p$ (I think this should be strongly connected to the theorem) and that the $(p^2-1)$-th is also divisible by $p$.

Can you prove these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $p$ is an odd prime then
$$2\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{qp+r}=\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1}{qp+r}+\frac{1}{qp+p-r}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{(q+1)p}{(qp+r)(qp+p-r)}$$
therefore $p$ divides the numerator of $\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{qp+r}$ (actually it can be seen that also $p^2$ divides it).

Moreover, by Wolstenholme's theorem, $p^2$ divides the numerator of $H_{p-1}$.

We have that
$$H_{p(p-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{p(p-1)}\frac{1}{n}=
\sum_{q=0}^{p-2}\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{qp+r}+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{q=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{q}\implies \mbox{$$p divides the numerator of $H_{p(p-1)}$}$$
and
$$H_{p^2-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{p^2-1}\frac{1}{n}=
H_{p(p-1)}+\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{(p-1)p+r}\implies \mbox{$$p divides the numerator of $H_{p^2-1}$}.$$

Comment: 'actually it can be seen that also $p^2$' divides it'  can you give a hint on how I can see that $p^2$ divides it?

Comment: @Nesa see Lemma 3.1: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1048515811

Comment: @Nesa I am surprised... Why did you unaccept my answer? Something wrong?

Comment: @Robert_Z For a moment, I didn't see why p-divisibility was transitive to addition, I re-accepted it